# Unicode strings in Django + SQLite

Tags: python, django, unicode

I have a model in Django 1.6:

```
class Text(models.Model):
  text = models.CharField()
  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.text
```

I have a cyrillic text stored in the table in this field.

When I try to request the object from table in the Django shell I get confusing result:

```
print t
```

Returns the correct string stored in the table

```
print t.text
```

Returns `u'u\0427u\0438'`

Why doesn't it return the field value properly?

Comment: No, it would return `u'\u0427\u0438'`, but only if you forgot to use `print`. You are looking at the `repr()` value of a unicode string, a debugging tool showing you the string literal representation using escape codes for non-ASCII non-printable codepoints.

Comment: OK, but when I use `print` function it gives an error:
`print t` outputs the correct string, `print t.text` gives an error: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1...`

Comment: That is because you are printing Unicode to a terminal that only supports ASCII. Good thing the `repr()` only uses ASCII codepoints and escapes the rest. :-)

Comment: But `print t` outputs the string properly in the same terminal. This is not the problem of terminal not showing ASCII, I guess.

Comment: The `t.__str__` method encodes the unicode string for you. `print` uses `sys.stdout.encoding` to try and do the same, and that is set to `ASCII` for some reason. This depends on the terminal or console you are using, some IDEs don't set this correctly.

Comment: And what function should I use with `t.text` to print it properly in the terminal? By the way, you should post an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: What happens if you run: `print u'\u0427\u0438'` the same way you run `print t.text`?

Comment: Yes, I get the same error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `print`, Python will try to encode Unicode values to the terminal or console codec using `sys.stdout.encoding`; if this is set to an encoding that is not capable of encoding your data then a `UnicodeEncodingException` is thrown.

You tried used `repr()` on the other hand, or simply let `t.text` echo in an interactive session, which comes down to the same thing. `repr()` will give you a ASCII-safe representation of a string literal, a value that can be pasted right back into the interpreter to recreate the string. To keep this ASCII-safe, all codepoints that are not printable ASCII characters are represented using escape sequences instead; newlines become `\n` again, and codepoints passed the Latin-1 range use `\uxxxx` representations.

When you use `print model` on the other hand, the default [`.__str__()` method on models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/unicode/#choosing-between-str-and-unicode) is used; this method encodes the Unicode value returned by your `.__unicode__()` method to UTF-8.

If you are seeing correct output when using `print t`, an exception for `print t.text` and `print repr(t.text)` works, your terminal is incorrectly configured. You can explicitly encode values in that case, to UTF-8 since that already worked for you:

```
print t.text.encode('utf8')
```